# Finding sum of 2 variables from 1 statement in C

Tags: c, sum

I recently started learning C and must create program that scanf two integer values from standard input separated by a space then printf the sum of these two integers. Must be able to accept negative values. I'm using repl.it to write code 1st then pasting in .c to compile.

Attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   int j = 0;
   printf("Enter 2 integers separated by space and press enter:\n");
   while (scanf("%d", &j) == 1) { 
      printf("Here is the sum:"%d", j);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Except this prints

```
Here is the sum: 1Here is the sum: 2
```

The output is wrong so what mistake did I make? Whats the correct method to get expected values?

(eg 1+2=3)

Comment: If you're trying to sum 2 integers, that won't work. Just `scanf` into 2 separate variables and then add them.

Comment: Wouldn't you expect to perform an addition somewhere?

Comment: `int a, b;` then `if (scanf ("%d %d", &a, &b) != 2) { /* handle error */ } printf ("sum: %d\n", a + b);`

Comment: The problem does not call for a loop.  You need to get _exactly_ two values (suggesting two variables).  As well and not taking input as described by the problem, you have made no attempt to to actually add the input values.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 The problem explicitly states to add 2 numbers from 1 scanf statement.

Comment: @stark I can't find a simple enough explanation and example that fits this problem. Please explain how I might do so or link some resources that meet aforementioned reqs.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I can't link to a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect. It does not even compile due to `"Here is the sum:"%d"` ill formatted string. The program will repetitively  scan an integer from standard input and print it as it was result of a sum.

Parsing two integers separated by a space can be easily done with `scanf()` function by using `"%d %d"` pattern. The function `scanf()` returns a number of successfully parsed arguments thus value of `2` is expected on correct input. Finally, add both number and print the result.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   int i, j;
   if (scanf("%d %d", &i, &j) == 2) { 
      printf("Here is the sum: %d\n", i + j);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I got this 

["main.c:4:1: error: expected identifier or '(']
[if (scanf("%d %d", &i, &j) == 2) { ]
[^]
[1 error generated.]

(exit status 1")

Comment: @JanusP The code is a _fragment_ not a complete solution.  It is the _body_ of the `main()` function you already have.  tstanisl has not unreasonably assumed you knew enough to understand what constitutes a valid program in C.  The point is you need an additional variable (`i`), and to replace your `while` loop with the `if` shown.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.